# Происхождение названия оружия "сашка"

Tags: этимология

Приветствую! Очень интересует происхождение слова `сашка`, в смысле оружия шашки.

Comment: Хотелось бы видеть письменно зафиксированный пример использования. Возможно, просто фонетический вариант именно "шашки"

Answer (score 1):

Происхождение слова "сашка" самое простое. Это языковое "народное творчество":
сабля + шашка = сашка. И ничего более, если подумать.

Answer (score 1):

**ШАШКА** это , насколько известно , холодное оружие казаков . Донских казаков . Происхождение казаков от хазарских евреев факт очевидный . Казаков , не случайно , часто называли **казарой** (и сами они себя тоже ) . В советском худ. кинофильме Чапаев : "**Казара** теперь до Гурьева пятки смазала !" . Русские летописи этноним *хазары* воспроизводят , как *козары* (через **К** , а не **Х**) . Само слово *казак* в переводе с иврита означает *сильный* (**חָזָק** **хазак**). В лексиконе казаков немало иврита . Например , такой характерный казачий атрибут , как **нагайка** . // Мальчику-казаку дарили **нагайку** *на первый зуб* ;  в Зап. Сечи атаману , при избрании , наносили три удара **нагайкой** , чтоб не зазнавался ; запорожский казак в бою , если ломалась или терялась сабля , хватался за **нагайку** . // Этимологию **нагайка** связывают с народом *ногайцы* . С таким же успехом её могли бы назвать *чеченкой* или *татаркой* (чечены и татары тоже держали при себе это орудие для наказания коня , и с ними казаки контактировали куда больше , чем с ногайцами) . В действительности ,  **нагайка** это от ивритного **נֶגַע нага/нэга** - значения : *язва* , *рана* / *бедствие* , *бич* / *трогать* , *касаться* , -  **נָגַע בְּעֶצֶב רָגִיש**  **нага** *беэцев рагиш* - *затронул за живое* . (*Примечание : иврит читается справа-налево* .) Теперь перейдём к **ШАШКЕ** . Ивритное **שש сас**/**шаш**  /в современном иврите/   означает *радоваться* , но связано и боем , - **שָׂשׂ אֵלֵי קרָב  сас элэй крав** переводится , как *рвался в бой* (*элэй* - предлог типа *к* / *крав* - *бой* , *сражение*) . Ниже , скриншот из ИРИС-словаря д-ра Баруха Подольского [ИРИС-словарь.](http://www.slovar.co.il/translate.php) ============================================================================= [image: сас- шаш] ===========================================================================       В силу того , что ивритная буква **שׂ** шин/син озвучивается двояко - как **С** и **Ш** , а в классическом иврите нет гласных букв , как таковых , - это **САС** может быть произнесено и , как **ШАШ** или , даже , **САШ** . Отсюда **ШАШКА** , то есть СТРЕМЯЩАЯСЯ , РВУЩАЯСЯ [В БОЙ ] . Возможна и форма **САШКА** .